Delphi FMX SearchBox
I have a project in Delphi FMX for Android and Windows platform on which I need to have a search box. The search box must have a search string input option, which when a character is entered automatically filters the data and displays only those matching the search string in a drop down list. Clicking on a selected entry in the drop-down list shall cause the search field to record the selected string.
I approached the problem by adding a search box consisting of a TSearchBox in a TComboBox
.
The TComboBox is binded to the TQuery with the data. I filter the data in the TQuery according to the string input in the TSearchBox and display the drop-down menu of the TComboBox.
The problem is that the list in TComboBox is refreshed only if I shrink and expand the drop-down menu again, and that when I click on a selected item in the list, the ComboBox1Click procedure is not executed.
My code is like this:
TfrmMain.SearchBox1Typing(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.BeginUpdate;
  dmCC.FDQuery1.Filtered := False;
  dmCC.FDQuery1.Filter := '';
  if SearchBox1.Text <> '' then
  begin
    dmCC.FDQuery1.OnFilterRecord := nil;
    dmCC.FDQuery1.Filter := 'UPPER(name) LIKE ''/' + UpperCase(SearchBox1.Text) + '%'' ESCAPE ''/''';
    dmCC.FDQuery1.Filtered := True;
  end;
  ComboBox1.EndUpdate;
  // shrink and expand the drop-down menu to refresh data
  ComboBox1.DropDown;
  if NOT ComboBox1.DroppedDown then
  begin
    ComboBox1.DropDown;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.ComboBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SearchBox1.Text := ComboBox1.Text;
end;

Does anyone have any idea how to implement such a search box?

I don't have any answer, but I notice (with surprise) that the search box's Text property remains unchanged in all OnTyping events. The Text property seems to change only after focus leaves the search box. Might this be a bug in Delphi?

@MatthiasB If you want to be notified after typing each character separately into Search Box you should use OnChangeTracking event instead.

I wrote this post in my blog 5 years ago.
I also wrote a tutorial
Sorry, all in French.
Hope it can help

Hello.
Thank you for your solution SergeGirard. I have already solved the problem, in a slightly different way, but thank you for the solution. This was the solution I was looking for.
